# ajax jquery зависает браузер

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Отправляю ajax запрос на добавления task. После срабатывания  - браузер зависает. Tak добавляется в DB. На странице добавления отображается, но колесиком прокрутить вниз страницу не получается.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#form_add_task").submit(function () { 
        var form = $(this); 
        var error = false; 

        if (!error) {
            var data = form.serialize();
           alert(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: '/listControllers/CreateController', 
                data: data, 
                async: true,
                cache: false,

                success: function (response) { 

                    if (response) {
                        $('#res').html(response); 
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                    alert(xhr.status); 
                    alert(thrownError); 
                },

            });
        }

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Консоль выводит:

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

Comment: что в консоли при этом?

Comment: @Tsyklop, добавил в описание

Comment: Версия `jQuery`? Может устарела?

Comment: @webDev_ какая актуальна?

Comment: У вас на странице только один запрос? Ошибка в том, что запрос вызывается синхронно, но судя по приведенному коду запрос асинхронный.

Comment: а на стороне контролера может где быть ошибка?

Comment: Единственное, jquery у меня подключено следующим образом: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`